# `SIGTTOU` signal to the background process

Tags: bash, shell, signals

As per the [post](http://linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php), which says that[emphasis mine]:

> If a process within a background job ***tries to write to a TTY device, the TTY sends a SIGTTOU signal to the entire job***. This will normally suspend the job. It is possible to turn off this feature on a per-TTY basis.

If I understand that statement correctly, there should be no output when invoking `ls / &` since the `ls` would receive the `SIGTTOU` signal when trying to write out, which would suspend the running of `ls`.

But there is output in the terminal when calling `ls /&`, which is really out of my expectation.

Here is the output:

```
ls /  &  
[1] 75297
jhon@desktop:~$ initrd.img  lib32   lost+found  opencv_4.0.tar.gz  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
bin                    data-ceph  data2  etc                 lfs         lib64   media       opt                root           srv   usr  zeus
boot                   data.bk    dev    home                lib         libx32  mnt         proc               run            sys   var
#the cursor twinkles until I hit the enter key.
#empty line
[1]+  Done                    ls /
jhon@desktop:~$
```

Am I misunderstanding the aforementioned statement? If I am wrong, please let me know.

***What's more***, it seems that no `SIGTOU` signal is ever sent to `ls`. Here is the output of `strace ls /  &`

```
strace ls /  &
[1] 80908
jhon@desktop::~$ execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "/"], [/* 29 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9d8000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=122346, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 122346, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f00e80f2000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0[\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=134296, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00e80f1000
mmap(NULL, 2238192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f00e7ccb000
mprotect(0x7f00e7ceb000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f00e7eea000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f000) = 0x7f00e7eea000
mmap(0x7f00e7eec000, 5872, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00e7eec000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\34\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31168, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2126336, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f00e7ac3000
mprotect(0x7f00e7aca000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f00e7cc9000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f00e7cc9000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P \2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1857312, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3965632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f00e76fa000
mprotect(0x7f00e78b8000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f00e7ab8000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1be000) = 0x7f00e7ab8000
mmap(0x7f00e7abe000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00e7abe000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\27\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=252032, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00e80f0000
mmap(NULL, 2347200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f00e74bc000
mprotect(0x7f00e74f9000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f00e76f8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3c000) = 0x7f00e76f8000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f00e72b8000
mprotect(0x7f00e72bb000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f00e74ba000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f00e74ba000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18624, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f00e70b3000
mprotect(0x7f00e70b7000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f00e72b6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f00e72b6000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00e80ef000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00e80ed000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f00e80ed840) = 0
mprotect(0x7f00e7ab8000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f00e72b6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f00e74ba000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f00e76f8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f00e7cc9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f00e7eea000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x619000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f00e8110000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f00e80f2000, 122346)          = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffcbb368ce0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffcbb368ce0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(0)                                  = 0x9d8000
brk(0x9f9000)                           = 0x9f9000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00e810f000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tr"..., 1024) = 400
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f00e810f000, 4096)            = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=35, ws_col=169, ws_xpixel=169, ws_ypixel=35}) = 0
stat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 38 entries */, 32768)    = 1080
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 89), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00e810f000
write(1, "VCAST_GUI_SIZES.plist  data\t  da"..., 140VCAST_GUI_SIZES.plist  data   data1  dms_windows_server  initrd.img  lib32   lost+found  opencv_4.0.tar.gz  reportlog.log  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
) = 140
write(1, "bin\t\t       data-ceph  data2  et"..., 96bin                data-ceph  data2  etc                 lfs         lib64   media       opt                root           srv   usr  zeus
) = 96
write(1, "boot\t\t       data.bk\t  dev\t home"..., 88boot                     data.bk    dev    home                lib         libx32  mnt         proc               run             sys   var
) = 88
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f00e810f000, 4096)            = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

[1]+  Done                    strace ls /
```

Comment: You need to use `stty tostop` to turn on this feature.

Comment: @Barmar Yup, thank you for pointing out that. One more question, why the cursor ***always twinkles*** until I hit the enter key when invoking `ls \ &` without setting `stty tostop`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the cursor twinkling.